# How to make a specific attribute as a primary key in python

Tags: python

I had a small requirement of making a specific attribute as primary key, such that by using this attribute I want to access the other attributes of the same row. Could any one help me please.

Description:: I had 4 arrays and I want to retrieve the data in the arrays corresponding to the row I have selected.In simple terms I am using Python as a database and store the retrieve the values of other tuples basing on a specific column value.

```
import string
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import win32com.client

win = Tk()
win.title("Sorting the list of employees as of desire")
win.geometry("600x600+200+50")
win.resizable()

class Emp(object):
    def __init__(self):
        i = 0


        def save():            
            b = self.e.get()
            #print "The name of employee is", b
            n.append(b) 

            c = self.a.get()
            #print "The age of employee is", c
            ge.append(c)  

            idf = self.i.get()
            #print "The Ide of the Employee is ", id            
            idee.append(idf)  

            de = self.d.get()
            # print "The Designation of the Employee is ", de            
            desi.append(de) 

            #print "\n"


        def clear():
            self.e.delete(0, END)
            self.a.delete(0, END)
            self.i.delete(0, END)
            self.d.delete(0, END)

        n = []
        Label(text="Employee form ", font="Verdana 18 bold italic").pack()
        Name = Label(text="Name ", font="Verdana 10 bold ")
        Name.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.5)
        Name.pack()
        self.e = Entry(text="Enter the name of the employee ")
        self.e.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
        self.e.insert(0, "Name of Employee")
        self.e.pack()

        ge = []
        age = Label(text="Age ", font="Verdana 10 bold ")
        age.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.5)
        age.pack()
        self.a = Entry(text="Enter the age of the employee ")
        self.a.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
        self.a.insert(0, "Age of Employee")
        self.a.pack()

        idee = []
        ide = Label(text="ID ", font="Verdana 10 bold ")
        ide.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.5)
        ide.pack()
        self.i = Entry(text="Enter the ID of the employee ")
        self.i.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
        self.i.insert(0, "IDE of Employee")
        self.i.pack()


        desi = []
        des = Label(text="Designation ", font="Verdana 10 bold ")
        des.place(relx=0.1, rely=0.5)
        des.pack()
        self.d = Entry(text="The Designation of the employee ")
        self.d.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor=CENTER)
        self.d.insert(0, "Designation of Employee")
        self.d.pack()

        def printf():
            global i 

            xyz = len(n)
            for i in range(0, xyz):
                print "Details are ::", "Name is :", n[i], "Age is : ", ge[i], "Employee Id is :", idee[i], "Designation is :", desi[i] 
                print "\n"

        def sorting():
            sor = raw_input("Enter a to sort from A or z to sort in reverse order")
            xyz = len(n)
            if sor == 'a' or'A' :
                n.sort()
                for i in range(0, xyz):
                    print "Details are ::", "Name is :", n[i]#, "Age is : ", ge[i], "Employee Id is :", idee[i], "Designation is :", desi[i] 
                    print "\n"
            elif sor == 'z' or 'Z':
                n.sort()
                print "Details are ::", "Name is :", n[i], "Age is : ", ge[i], "Employee Id is :", idee[i], "Designation is :", desi[i] 
                n.reverse()
                for i in range(0, xyz):
                    print "Details are ::", "Name is :", n[i]#, "Age is : ", ge[i], "Employee Id is :", idee[i], "Designation is :", desi[i] 
                    print "\n"

        btn = Button(text="Save ", font="verdana 12 ", command=save)
        btn.pack(fill=X, expand=YES)
        btn.place(relx=0.85, rely=0.06, anchor=CENTER)

        btnc = Button(text="Next", font="verdana 12 ", command=clear)
        btnc.pack(fill=X, expand=YES)
        btnc.place(relx=0.85, rely=0.90, anchor=CENTER)      

        btnp = Button(text="print", font="verdana 12 ", command=printf)
        btnp.pack(fill=X, expand=YES)
        btnp.place(relx=0.6, rely=0.9, anchor=CENTER)      

        btns = Button(text="Sort", font="verdana 12 ", command=sorting)
        btns.pack(fill=X, expand=YES)
        btns.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.9, anchor=CENTER)





abj = Emp()
win.mainloop()
```

This is my code. After storing all the values in the respective arrays.I want to sort them basing on name, to the code I have written the output I got is the sorted array of only the name attribute, Instead I want all the corresponding values also to be sorted.Please help me

Comment: Could you post some code to illustrate what you've tried, what output you're getting, and what output you want?

Comment: I have given my code.. please go through it and priovide me the ans

Comment: Thanks for providing the code, but you've erased the original question, making the comments in this thread so-far less useful. Could you please re-post the original question's content, with your code below that? Thanks.

Comment: What is the primary key?

Comment: the array named n is to used as primary key for the values that are stored in the respective indecies

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about... "primary key" and "row" are concepts that have to do with a database. You have no database here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Replying to original question** (it's been erased):

You could use a python dict: http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.

```
dataset = {}
dataset['key1'] = (value_1_1, value_1_2, value_1_3, value_1_4)
dataset['key2'] = (value_2_1, value_2_2, value_2_3, value_2_4)
```

Then if you wanted the values associated with 'key2':

```
row_of_interest = dataest['key2']
```

**In the context of your code, using a dict:**

More specifically, after seeing your code, one solution would be to change your save function to this:

```
def save():
    name = self.e.get()
    age = self.a.get()
    employee_id = self.i.get()
    employee_designation = self.d.get()
    self.employees[name] = (age, employee_id, employee_designation)
```

where `employees` is a dict. This gives you your primary key property stated in your question, but doesn't give you easy access to sorted results as your code hints at.

**OR, using a list:**

```
def save():
    name = self.e.get()
    age = self.a.get()
    employee_id = self.i.get()
    employee_designation = self.d.get()
    self.employees.append((name, age, employee_id, employee_designation))
```

where `employees` is a list, not a dict. Then you can use the `sorted` built-in function (http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#sorted) combined with the `operator` module to get your sorted results:

```
sorted(self.employees, key=operator.itemgetter(0), reverse=False)
```

This gives you easy access to results sorted by the first element (the names), but doesn't treat any of the attributes as a special primary key.

Comment: Dude your ans is r8 but it is not the thing I  had asked. please have a glance towards the question.

Comment: I had a glance towards the question. Perhaps you could write a clearer question if I have misunderstood you. I'm assuming you could put the values of your 4 arrays as the elements of the value tuples in the python dict. You could use the primary key that you have in mind as the key for the dictionary. That seems to satisfy the constraints of your question.

Comment: I have given my code.. please go through it and priovide me the ans

Answer (score 0):

In the manner your code is written, your related data sets (I presume that they are `n`, `ge`, `idee`, and `desi` aren't related to one another.  You attempt to sort the list of names  by `n.sort()`, but that won't work; the data is loosely coupled.

Since you're attempting to sort the data based **specifically** on an individual employee's name, then the most ideal solution would be to use a dictionary.  As touched on by @Sancho before, a Python dictionary allows you to create a relationship between a key (in this case, the employee's name) and values (in this case, whatever attributes the employee has afterwards).

(I use "related" to each other tongue-in-cheek, since it's clear to the programmer that the datasets *are* related, but in Python's world, they're just four lists that have no bearing between each other.  Using the dictionary is the better solution in this case.)